# Python in powershell is giving me an import error when I try to import the module called urlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program uses this module, and here is the lines of code I put in order to import urlib:

```
import random
from urlib.request import urlopen
import sys
```

Python gives the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oop_Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from urlib.request import urlopen
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlib'
```

From the other questions that were similar to this, the answer seems to be that Python 3 changed the way you import the module. From what I found, my code is compatible with Python 3, and yet it still gives me the error: what am i doing wrong or do you need more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the module is `urllib` not `urlib`.